# Type B uncertainties and statistical analysis

Tags: references, measurement-error, uncertainty, error-propagation

In the Guide to Uncertainty in Measurement (GUM), two classes of methods to evaluate uncertainties are distinguished : a type A evaluation is a statistical method, applicable when a set of independently repeated observations is available, and all others means are classified as type B methods.

Consider a voltmeter connected to some electrical circuit assumed to give a constant DC voltage, that we wish to measure. Due to (e.g. thermal) noise, the signal is actually not constant, but fluctuates around a average value.

On the one hand, using a set of measurements (repeated in time) and a type A evaluation, the average value of the series of observation and the experimental variance of this average value can be evaluated : they provide a measurement result and a type A standard uncertainty. With a large enough number of data points, the standard uncertainty can be made as small as one wishes (and in this case, it is not difficult to get a very large number of experimental observations).

On the other hand, a *type B* evaluation of a single result the voltmeter requires to take into account the nominal precision given in its datasheet.

(The question is obviously not specific to voltmeters!)

As long as the type A uncertainty for the set of observations $u(\overline{x})$ is large with respect to the single-result type B uncertainty $u(x_i)$, I have to problem to trust the correctness of the type A uncertainty $u(\overline{x})$. However, I am confused to what happens when they become of the same order of magnitude. I was not able to find a discussion of this point in the GUM or its supplements (perhaps I missed them). I see different/related possibilities, but which are not satisfactory :

- switch to type B evaluation: but in this case, how to take into account the additional uncertainty due to the noise ?
- consider $y=\overline{x} = (x_1 + \cdots + x_N)/N$ as a composite quantity and use the composite error propagation: but in this case, how to experimentally determine the covariance $\text{cov}(x_i,x_j)$ ?
- combine the standard uncertainties from type A and type B in quadrature, as $\sqrt{u_{\text{type A}}^2(\overline{x}) + u_{\text{type B}}^2(x_i)}$, but I don't see why this would be justified (in the GUM framework) ?

Is there a standard way to treat this situation ?

Thanks